# Using htaccess to display domain name during maintenance mode

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

When my site is in maintenance mode, I use my .htaccess file to redirect any visitors to a designated maintenance page.

The code works perfectly fine, but instead of displaying the path to my maintenance page in the address bar, I'd like for my domain name to be shown instead. So, rather than showing 'www.mysite.com/maintenance.html' in the address bar when visitors are redirected, I'd like for 'www.mysite.com' to be shown instead. Is this possible?

this code I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^[my ip address]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.png$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.gif$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.js$

RewriteRule $ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: You could try removing the **R=302** flag from your rewrite rule.

Comment: Spoke too soon. It only works partially: when I try to access any other page but the domain index, I'm redirected to the maintenance page, however the 'under maintenance' image and css do not appear. I only get the text unstyled on a blank white page.

Answer (score 0):

> Spoke too soon. It only works partially: when I try to access any other page but the domain index, I'm redirected to the maintenance page, however the 'under maintenance' image and css do not appear. I only get the text unstyled on a blank white page.

It looks like you want to do a couple of things.

1. Under maintenance mode, you want to redirect all requests to the root page (e.g. http://www.mysite.com/)
2. The root page will display what's in /maintenance.html

So we need to address these 2 things separately:

```
# for #1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^[my ip address]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.png$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.gif$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.js$
RewriteRule $ / [R=302,L]

# for #2 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^[my ip address]
RewriteRule ^$ /maintenance.html
```